# SwiftUI status bar getting hidden when increasing font size with dynamic text

Tags: swift, swiftui, safearea

I have a view with a picker at the top of this view. the code works as I suppose. The app is for blind and visually impaired people. If these people use dynamic font on their iPhone and maximize the font, the picker moves under the status bar. How can I avoid the picker being pushed under the status bar?

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Picker("Medien", selection: $selectedMedia) {
      ForEach(media, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
          .font(.title)
      }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.segmented)

    if selectedMedia == "Podcasts" {
      PodcastPlayerView()
        .padding()
    } else {
      RadioPlayerView()
        .padding()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use a `ScrollView` so that the content scrolls rather than pushing to the edges.

Comment: yes, and you can also add .contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior(.never)